# Raster pixel size in QGIS automatically defaults to square

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3, cell-size

I am using QGIS 3.4 and my data consists of rasters with irregular cell sizes. In ArcGIS Pro, the cell sizes are maintained (screenshot below).

[image: see screenshot here]

However, when I upload the same raster into QGIS, the cell size gets automatically changed to square, with one dimension of the pixel size being negative (screenshot below).

[image: see screenshot here]

I think QGIS is automatically resampling the data and formatting to square cells, which I want to avoid. Is this a functionality that I can edit somewhere within QGIS?

Comment: Just opening an image file should not change it's pixel size or the size of the image. Your image was 260x231, QGIS shows 336x90. Are you sure that you have  not done any processing for the image?

Comment: No processing; I'm opening up the same file in both Arc and Q. I noticed that too and I don't understand why that happens.

Comment: Can you share test data?